# How we can charge a 5V device using a generic source of energy, monitoring the input voltage in real time

Tags: pcb-design

[image]

We have made a PCB using a MIC2876 to boost a 2.5V/4.5V 0.5 A input voltage to 5V output to be able to feed any device connected to two USB ports (USB-C and USB-A.)

We've also implemented a current sensor connected to an LED strip to monitor the incoming energy level.

We tested the unit by applying an input voltage in the range of 2.5V to 4.5V 0.5A but instead of boosting to 5V the output voltage is  the same as the input - it fails its purpose.

We have tried to replace the IC and also built other PCBs but with the same result.  We also tried to remove the current sensor to make sure  it was not producing an excessive resistance, drawing all the incoming current but that didn't help, either.

Do you have any idea of what could cause the malfunction and do you have any suggestion to improve, if possible, the design?

I additionally add:

(a) photos of the PCB;

(b) PCB layout diagram (all layers separately)

(c) link to the datasheet for your inductor.

(d) Also, the schematic shows p/n MIC2876-AYMT (the adjustable and fixed version)

(a)
[image]

(b1)
[image]

(b2)
[image]

(b3)
[image]

(c)

[Datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/ihlp_2525cz_01-1763244.pdf)

(d)
[image]

Comment: Andrea - Hi, Please [edit] your question to add: (a) photos of your hardware; (b) PCB layout diagram (all layers separately) from your EDA software; (c) link to the datasheet for your inductor. (d) Also, the schematic shows p/n MIC2876-AYMT (the *adjustable* version) but pin 5 is labeled "OUTS" which applies to the *fixed* output versions. Which IC do you really have? (e) Have you used an oscilloscope on the MIC2876 pin 1 to see if it is actually switching at all? (f) What other troubleshooting have you done, apart from replacing that IC? Any other measurements or test results you can report?

Comment: Hi Sam, I add the infomation requested

Comment: The schematic you posted won't work since the out sense pin is hooked up like the feedback pin would be if you had the adjustable version.  Did you actually build the schematic you posted or a different one with the pins hooked up correctly?

Comment: @Andrea - I'm busy here, so other people will likely give replies before me. Briefly: (g) (I think this is what *user1850479* is referring to), that photo shows an IC with top marking `76H` but *I think* the adjustable version would be marked `76A`. I couldn't quickly find what version is marked `76H`, but I'm concerned it's not the correct part for the schematic. (h) The lack of oscilloscope traces will affect your troubleshooting - DMM measurements are not enough (IMHO). (i) You said: "*In the fixed output version, the resistors were desoldered*" Double-check if that is the correct change.

Comment: Thanks for this Sam, but please consider , on the image I just attached on the left is the circuit for the fixed version that I made by desoldering the resistors and short-circuiting the pin outs and out, and with the variable version I used the resistors as in the picture. I'll try to find an oscilloscope somewhere and record the characteristic I'll send you

Comment: @Andrea - Last comment from me for a while: "*on the image I just attached on the left is the circuit for the fixed version that I made by desoldering the resistors and short-circuiting the pin outs and out, and with the variable version I used the resistors as in the picture*" (j) How do you know that the IC in the photo is an adjustable one? (k) In the question, you didn't say that you (correctly) shorted `OUTS` and `OUT`, just that you removed the (feedback voltage divider) resistors. That is why I asked you to double check in my point (i). Anyway, I look forward to oscillograms. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Tony, modifications has been applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response but we had a lot of trouble during testing so we have to undergo few twice with different tools.

At the end the main problem was that we took reference schematic which is for variable-voltage IC, while fixed version was soldered.

Some of you spot the problem immediately but when we undergo troubleshooting purchasing a variable IC version and soldering on the board the issue remain (probably because our tool could not control the heat used during the soldering process)
My mistake was also not providing this forum with the BOM list, it will probably lead immediately to the real problem and make it unquestionable.

Now we are going to change the configuration to support the fixed version and also we will place the input capacitors closer to the IC to reduce the noise.

My apologies again for the time you lose and my compliments for your efficiency in spotting the root cause almost at once.